# Running two threads in same time ( multithreading?)

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to get two threads to work in same time.
Let me explain with code:

Main Class that runs both threads

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    abThread.move(5);
    cdThread.move(5);
}
```

Thread 1:

```
static void move(int i) {
    int min = 0;
    int max = 100;

    while (i > 0) {
        int a = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);
        //  try {
        //      Thread.sleep(100);
        //  } catch (Exception e) {
        //  }

        if ((a % 2) == 1) {
            System.out.println("a");
            i -= 1; 
            continue;
        } else {
            System.out.println("b");
            i -= 1; 
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Thread 2:

```
static void move(int i) {
    int min = 0;
    int max = 100;

    while (i > 0) {
        int a = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);
        //  try {
        //      Thread.sleep(100);
        //  } catch (Exception e) {
        //  }

        if ((a % 2) == 1) {
            System.out.println("c");
            i -= 1; 
            continue;
        } else {
            System.out.println("d");
            i -= 1; 
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

Im getting random a/b x 5 and after 5 of them im getting random (c/d) x5

My goal is to get a/b,c/d,a/b,c/d... and so on

Any help or redirection to some way-would greatly appreciate it!

Edit: Notice i tryed with try sleep but it just postpones how long before next a/b after a/b. Only way i could do it a/b,c/b would be

```
    abThread.move(1);
    cdThread.move(1);
    abThread.move(1);
```

......

Thanks

Comment: You appear to be doing all the work in your main thread, and none in the threads represented by `abThread` and `cdThread`.  Invoking a method on a `Thread` instance does not cause the work to be performed in the thread of execution represented by that object.

Comment: Yeah so, any idea, direction? :)

Answer (score 0):

The work performed by a thread other than the main one is determined by the `Runnable` with which it was initialized or by the implementation of its `run()` method if you've overridden that.  One of those places is where you should be placing the invocations of the various `move()` methods.  Then your main thread should `start()` both thread instances.

That (probably) achieves the threads running in parallel, subject to thread scheduling and the availability of execution resources.  As @Alexander described, however, it does not necessarily produce perfect alternation between the outputs of the two threads, nor does it even guarantee that any of the output produced by one thread will appear before any of the output produced by the other.

If you need perfect alternation then the two threads need to synchronize with each other to take turns.  There is a large number of ways you could implement that, but if you want it, it needs to be built in to your `move()` methods.  The low-level, old-school ways revolve around using the `wait()` and `notify()` / `notifyAll()` methods of a shared object.  You might also use a `SynchronousQueue` for just two threads taking turns, among many other possibilities.

Comment: Thank you for sparing time to elaborate. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to experiment with threads, not only print characters alternately, you could try something like this:

First of all, implement `Runnable` that holds code to be run by threads:

```
class Task implements Runnable {
    //c1 and c2 are characters to print (a,b and c,d for example)
    private final String c1, c2;
    //semaphore guarantees the order of threads execution
    private final Semaphore sync;
    private int i;

    Task(int i, String c1, String c2, Semaphore sync) {
        this.i = i;
        this.c1 = c1;
        this.c2 = c2;
        this.sync = sync;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            int min = 0;
            int max = 100;
            while (i > 0) {
                sync.acquire();
                int a = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);
                if ((a % 2) == 1) {
                    System.out.println(c1);
                    i -= 1;
                } else {
                    System.out.println(c2);
                    i -= 1;
                }
                sync.release();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Then create `Semaphore`:

```
Semaphore sync = new Semaphore(0, true);
```

Create two threads and run them:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Task(10, "a", "b", sync));
Thread t2 = new Thread(new Task(10, "c", "d", sync));

t1.start();
t2.start();
```

And finally release semaphore so that one of the threads waiting on it can proceed:

```
sync.release();
```

Answer (score -1):

The threads run at their own pace, getting scheduled on and off the CPU as the Operating System desires. You can only expect to get `a/b, c/d, a/b, c/d, ...` execution if the Operating System uses round-robin scheduling (i.e. every thread gets a turn, in a circle), which it almost certainly doesn't.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't look like that's the OP's main problem.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yeah, I noticed your comment. But even if these methods running on separate threads, he still wouldn't get `a/b, c/d, a/b, c/d, ...`

Comment: So there is a workaround which you dont suggest me to use?

Comment: @joe123 IDK if this is just a contrived example to demonstrate your problem, or if it's your actual code. If it's your actual code, then why use threading at all? If you just need to print a or b, then c or d, then you can just call those method synchronously as you are, but with an argument of 1, not 5

Comment: @joe123 You're seeing 5 `a/b` followed by 5 `c/d` because you called each of those methods with the argument 5 to the parameter `i`. Accordingly, their while loops will loop 5 times each.

Comment: Could i like run a method that will do 5 times each lets call it runner and make him run ab then cd, 5 times?

Comment: @joe123 Yep :) Doesn't even need a method, tbh... `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { abThread.move(1); cdThread.move(1); }`